# Restore Default OSX Home Folder Icons

Tags: macos, dropbox

I want to keep folders such as Pictures and Documents in my home folder in sync between computers; at the moment, I'm using Dropbox to do this. On Computer A I added a symlink to the folders in my home directory to the Dropbox folder. On Computer B I deleted the existing Pictures and Documents folders and replaced them with symlinks to the folders in the Dropbox folder. This works very well, except that in Finder I don't see the nice little icons that Lion has by default for folders of a particular kind. Is there any way to restore these?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the icons, you can *Get Info* on a folder, and paste the icon over the current one.

I don't know if this will stick with Dropbox.